# SQL query with poor join performance

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle12c

I'm experiencing very poor performance in a query I've written for **Oracle** 12c. It's probably related to my inefficient use of joins and was hoping someone could help me out with where I'm going wrong. The query I have is currently **taking over a minute to run**.

I'm am trying to return the table and column names where:

- The column belongs to a Primary Key
- The column type is Number
- The owner of the table is *MY_OWNER*
- The Primary Key is a single column constraint

Currently my query looks as follows

```
SELECT consCols.table_name, consCols.column_name 
FROM all_cons_columns consCols
INNER JOIN all_constraints cons 
  ON cons.constraint_name = consCols.constraint_name
INNER JOIN all_tab_columns cols 
  ON consCols.table_name = cols.table_name AND consCols.column_name = cols.column_name
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
AND cons.owner = 'MY_OWNER'
AND cols.data_type = 'NUMBER'
AND consCols.table_name IN(
  SELECT consCols2.table_name 
  FROM all_cons_columns consCols2
  INNER JOIN all_constraints cons2 
    ON cons2.constraint_name = consCols2.constraint_name
  WHERE cons2.constraint_type = 'P' 
  AND cons2.owner = 'MY_OWNER' 
  GROUP BY consCols2.table_name
  HAVING COUNT(consCols2.table_name) = 1
);
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Please run explain plan for the query and post results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would using analytic functions speed the query?

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM (SELECT consCols.table_name, consCols.column_name, cols.data_type,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY consCols.table_name) as cnt
      FROM all_cons_columns consCols INNER JOIN
           all_constraints cons 
           ON cons.constraint_name = consCols.constraint_name INNER JOIN
           all_tab_columns cols 
           ON consCols.table_name = cols.table_name AND consCols.column_name = cols.column_name
      WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND
            cons.owner = 'MY_OWNER'
     ) tc               
WHERE data_type = 'NUMBER' AND cnt = 1;
```

Or even aggregation?

```
  SELECT consCols.table_name, consCols.column_name
  FROM all_cons_columns consCols INNER JOIN
       all_constraints cons 
       ON cons.constraint_name = consCols.constraint_name INNER JOIN
       all_tab_columns cols 
       ON consCols.table_name = cols.table_name AND consCols.column_name = cols.column_name
  WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND
        cons.owner = 'MY_OWNER'
  GROUP BY consCols.table_name, consCols.column_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND
         MAX(cols.data_type) = 'NUMBER';
```

Here is a third option:

```
  SELECT consCols.table_name, consCols.column_name
  FROM all_cons_columns consCols INNER JOIN
       all_constraints cons 
       ON cons.constraint_name = consCols.constraint_name INNER JOIN
       all_tab_columns cols 
       ON consCols.table_name = cols.table_name AND consCols.column_name = cols.column_name
  WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND
        cons.owner = 'MY_OWNER' AND
        cols.data_type = 'NUMBER' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM all_cons_columns acc
                    WHERE acc.constraint_name = consCols.constraint_name AND
                          acc.table_name = consCols.table_name AND
                          acc.column_name <> consCols.column_name
                   );
```

This eliminates the aggregation and the lookup should be relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Both your answers take roughly 20 seconds so that's a win. Whilst I was hoping for a under 5 seconds this is still a significant improvement and helps me greatly.

Comment: Nice Answer. There is an small error in the aggregation SQL - remove the AND on the third-to-last line. I have found that data dictionary queries do take significantly longer since upgrading from 10g to 12c.

Comment: Correction, answer number one works great in about 20 seconds but answer 2 actually returns too many rows. That's fine though I can just stick with #1.
Also answer #3 doesn't work for me because all_constraints doesn't have a column_name column :(

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Number #3 works too now and also takes roughly 20 seconds. Is there any advantage between #1 and #3 that I should be concerned about? Any compatibility issues with older Oracle 11g servers?

Comment: @Venick . . . Nothing comes to mind as an issue between the first and third.  You must have a lot of constraints, tables, and columns.